# Update all same values in a row Mysql/PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using following code to update all same values in column with some other.

> UPDATE `ez_ccomment` SET `rating` = 's5.png' WHERE 'rating' =5;

Code is executing successfully but no changes are taking place.

Comment: You have the wrong kind of quotes around `rating`. You're testing whether the string `"rating"` is equal to 5, and it never is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't quote `rating`:

```
UPDATE ez_ccomment SET rating = 's5.png' WHERE rating =5;
```

or use backticks:

```
UPDATE ez_ccomment SET rating = 's5.png' WHERE `rating` = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have quotes for rating. Replace by backticks

```
UPDATE `ez_ccomment` SET `rating` = 's5.png' WHERE `rating` =5;
```